# Convert List<Foo> to List<Bar> by Mapping a Stream of List<Foo> into Map<Triple, List<Foo>> then Collecting to List<Bar>

Tags: java, compiler-errors, tuples, java-stream, collectors

I am trying to convert a List of one class of objects into a list of another class of objects while grouping by 3 attributes as an intermediate step. In order to do this, I am trying to stream the `List<Foo>` into a `Map<Triple<String, String, String>>, List<Foo>>`. However, when I then try to stream->map my newly created `Map<Triple, List>` into a `List<Bar>`, I encounter the following compilation error:

```
    [javac] /FooBarConversion.java:69: error: incompatible types: inference variable R has incompatible bounds
    [javac]                 .map(entry -> {
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac]     upper bounds: Object
    [javac]     lower bounds: void
    [javac]   where R,T are type-variables:
    [javac]     R extends Object declared in method <R>map(Function<? super T,? extends R>)
    [javac]     T extends Object declared in interface Stream
    [javac] 1 error
```

If I am reading this correctly, this seems to be telling me that I need to be mapping an `Object`, but what I actually receive is `void` i.e. the `map` can't do anything with nothing.

Is there something wrong with how I am using `Collectors.groupingBy` or am I misunderstanding something else?

This is the code that I have:

```java
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.ImmutableTriple;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Triple;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class FooBarConversion {

  public List<Bar> convertFooToBar(String type, List<Foo> fooList) {
    Map<Triple<String, String, String>, List<Foo>> fooMap = fooList.stream()
        .collect(
           Collectors.groupingBy(
             foo -> ImmutableTriple.of(foo.getFirstName(), foo.getMiddleName(), foo.getLastName())
           )
        );
    
    return fooMap.entrySet() // Set<Map<K,V>.Entry<Triple<...>, List<...>>>
      .stream()              // Stream<Map<K,V>.Entry<Triple<...>, List<...>>>
      .map(entry -> {        // THIS IS WHERE THE COMPILATION ERROR IS THROWN
         Triple<String, String, String> key = entry.getKey();
         
         Bar bar = Bar.builder()
           .withFirstName(key.getLeft())
           .withMiddleName(key.getMiddle())
           .withLastName(key.getRight())
           .build();

         // ETC. ETC.

         return bar;
         
      }).collect(Collectors.toList());       
  }
}
```

Reference Links:

- [Apache Triple](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Triple.html)
- [Apache Triple (GitHub)](https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Triple.java)
- [Apache ImmutableTriple (GitHub)](https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/ImmutableTriple.java)
- [Apache Pair](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html)
- [Baeldung | Collectors.groupingBy](https://www.baeldung.com/java-groupingby-collector)
- [Java 8 docs | Collectors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html)

Comment: So the lambda in `map()` will always return an instance of `Bar`? And did you try saving the stream into a variable after each call, i.e. `Stream<Entry<Triple<...>, List<...>> stream = fooMap.entrySet().stream(); Stream<Bar> barStream = stream.map(...); ...`? Sometimes the compiler has problems with type inference so you could try to see where it happens and help it out with some more code :)

Comment: It doesn't seem like the code you've posted can cause a type inference issue. I guess something appeared to be missing while *simplifying/obfuscating* the code. Can you provide a **minimal reproducible example** with these dummy `Foo/Bar` classes which would produce the same compilation error?

Comment: I wrote up a minimum reproducible example locally with some dummy values and I'm able to compile successfully, so I am now thinking that @Thomas is correct in saying that I likely need to help my compiler out a bit by splitting up the code into more steps. At the very least, that should help uncover if there is a detail I'm missing from consideration in my M.R.E.

Comment: @Thomas @Alexander it turns out that I was making a silly mistake. I was switching on `type` and then setting one of three attributes on `Bar` with an updated `List<Integer> values`. I was returning `bar.set<Type>Values(values)` from the `switch`, which is actually returning `void` (which makes sense). I was thinking that the setter returned the updated instance of Bar like in a Builder pattern. It ended up not being an issue with entry at all!

TL;DR: I was staring at my code for too long and overlooked that the I needed to return the updated instance itself to construct the List properly.